# How do I inherit from an ActionFilter attribute in a assembly in the same project but not directly referenced?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I am asking my not even be possible (I am skeptical) but I have been tasked to do this exact thing so please if its not possible or dumb please explain why.

I have a base project that contains an ActionFilter attribute that overrides OnActionExecuting.  It does nothing as it is supposed to be a base class to inherit from.

```
namespace mybaseproject
    public class BaseActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
      public string ActionName {get;set;}

      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
       }
     }
```

I have a second project that references 'mybaseproject' and uses BaseActionAttribute.

```
namesapce mysecondproject
public class MyController : Controller
{
 [BaseAction(ActionName="Index")]
 public ActionResult Index()
  {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

I have a third project that references both 'mybaseproject' and 'mysecondproject'.  It has an ActionFilterAttribute that inherits from the base one and has all of the real code to process.

```
using mybaseproject;
namespace mythirdproject
public class DerivedActionAttribute : BaseActionAttribute
        {
          public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
           {
             // do all the real stuff
             base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
           }
         }
```

What the desired effect is for the BaseActionAttribute in mysecondproject to use the code in DerivedActionAttribute of mythirdproject.  I don't see how this can work because mysecondproject has no reference to mythirdproject.  They just reside in the solution. I have tried using Authorize attribute as well but my breakpoint never gets hit in the derived attribute when I call my action in the second project.

This was how I was told to tackle the problem.  Either I misunderstood or am taking the wrong approach, or this is just not possible.

Which one?  Thanks ahead for listening.

Comment: You are correct, it's not possible.

Comment: Now I guess I will have to post a question on the workplace site on how to deal with my boss on telling him he is wrong.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. The mysecondproject should reference the mythirdproject and change the [BaseAction(ActionName="Index")] to [DerivedActionAttribute(ActionName="Index")]...

Comment: It cant. The second can only reference the base. That's the direct order.